# javascript prototype function gets ignored

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I'm having a

"Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

issue in my javascript object. How can I force the execution of the binding?

it happens when I call this function:

```
function ViewportDatasource(mockServer) {
        this.mockServer = mockServer;        
        this.connectionId =this.mockServer.connect(this.eventListener.bind(this));
    }
```

even if `eventListener` has been correctly defined in a prototype function

```
 ViewportDatasource.prototype.eventListener = function (event) {
        switch (event.eventType) {
            case 'rowCountChanged':
                this.onRowCountChanged(event);
                break;
            case 'rowData':
                this.onRowData(event);
                break;
            case 'dataUpdated':
                this.onDataUpdated(event);
                break;
        }
    };
```

What can I do?

To reply to Daniel's question, the instance gets called here:

```
 function setRowData($http) {
        // set up a mock server - real code will not do this, it will contact your
        // real server to get what it needs
        var mockServer = new MockServer();
        $http.get('data.json').then(function(response){
            mockServer.init(response.data);
        });

        var viewportDatasource = new ViewportDatasource(mockServer);
        table.api.setViewportDatasource(viewportDatasource);
        // put the 'size cols to fit' into a timeout, so that the scroll is taken into consideration
        setTimeout(function () {
            table.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        }, 100);
    }
```

This function gets executed after the ag-grid object in caller is ready

Comment: how are you constructing your instance? and when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ViewportDatasource(mockServer) {
    //the this operator here is undefined. function is not of object.
    this.mockServer = mockServer;        
    this.connectionId =this.mockServer.connect(this.eventListener.bind(this));
}
```

The this operator should be used only when you are binding the function to an object, in that case the this operator makes sense. In the above example it doesn't.

Comment: How can I correct it? How can I refer to the object itself then?